# How to generate binary powersets?

Tags: python, set

```
N = 3
```

desired output:

```
[(0,0,0), (0,0,1), (0,1,0), (0,1,1), (1,0,0), (1,0,1), (1,1,0), (1,1,1)]
```

This needs to work for any N, preferably up to at least 20.

I have played with the bin() function but I'm not quite sure how to do the rest.

Answer (score 4):

What you need is the "N-th Cartesian power" of `[0, 1]`. This is achieved with [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
In [1]: from itertools import product

In [2]: N = 3

In [3]: list(product([0, 1], repeat=N))
Out[3]: 
[(0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 1),
 (0, 1, 0),
 (0, 1, 1),
 (1, 0, 0),
 (1, 0, 1),
 (1, 1, 0),
 (1, 1, 1)]
```

As for efficiency, here's a simple timing comparison (I modified your function to return a list, since I'm testing on Python 3):

```
In [9]: %timeit x = prod(3)
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.96 µs per loop

In [10]: %timeit x = S(3)
100000 loops, best of 3: 18.2 µs per loop
```

Comment: Thanks! Will that be any more or less efficient than the loop I wrote below?

Comment: Thank you. At N=21 I think the gap widens exponentially. I watched it run for over a minute and it never completed. Itertools evaluated in seconds.

Answer (score 3):

Python 2 solution

`import itertools
list(itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=3))`

output

`[(0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 1),
 (0, 1, 0),
 (0, 1, 1),
 (1, 0, 0),
 (1, 0, 1),
 (1, 1, 0),
 (1, 1, 1)]`

Comment: Thanks! Will that be any more or less efficient than the loop I wrote below?

Comment: Far more efficient. `map` with user-defined functions is relatively slow, and your user-defined function defines a new function each time it is called to pass to the nested `map`.

Comment: Thanks. Mine was actually stalling at N=21 so I rewrote it with the itertools and it evaluated almost instantly. Orders of magnitude faster. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Is this efficient?

```
def S(N):
  return map(lambda m: map(lambda n: int(('{0:0' + str(N) + 'b}').format(m)[n]), range(N)), range(2**N))

print S(2)
> [[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]]
print S(3)
> [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
print S(4)
> [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
```